# How app can crash onpaint ? c#

Tags: c#, paint, paintevent

After entering pages I use refresh method to redraw controls. And if I look into task manager I can see what at first will be 40.000K memory, after entering another page it will be 50.000 and so on, but after reaching 100-130 or more and after some pages it will be again 100.

I creating only first time 100 controls where you can see in picture. If I try to go to next page it will update just values like game name, picture etc. I'm using onPaint event to draw controls and  for IDisposable controls making using()..Pages numbers is labels..
And all game controls are in floatLayout.Game controls is there where the picture is. I don't calling manualy paint events i'm just calling refresh or invalidate methods. And in second code sometimes I get nullReference exception, for e.graphics. e.graphics sometimes null.....I don't know why this is happening.

[image]
[image]

I don't know when but after some time and every time differently.
I dont know how to make program crash manually, this happens suddenly

And here my two codes:

My game control paint:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    base.OnPaint(e);

    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    if (this.ClientRectangle.Width > 0 && this.ClientRectangle.Height > 0)
        using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(this.ClientRectangle,
               Color.LightGray,
               Color.Silver,
               80F))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, this.ClientRectangle);
        }
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(componentBorderColor, 0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);

    if (AllGameInfoModel == null)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Kraunama" + loadingText, Namefont, NameBrush, 26, ControlHelpers.MeasureString("Kraunama", Namefont).Height / 2);
    }
    if (AllGameInfoModel != null)
    {
        NameTextSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(AllGameInfoModel.Name, Namefont);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(AllGameInfoModel.Name, Namefont, NameBrush, 26, ControlHelpers.MeasureString(AllGameInfoModel.Name, Namefont).Height / 3);

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(componentBorderColor, 0, 0, this.Width - 1, 24);

        if (showControl == false)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            if (makeBigerControl == false)
                coverLocationHeight = Height - 35;
            if (Cover != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Cover, new Rectangle(4, 30, coverLocationWidth, coverLocationHeight));
            }
            else
            {
                //Jei nėra paveikslėlio
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(CoverNoImage, new Rectangle(4, 30, coverLocationWidth, coverLocationHeight));

            }
            int LocationX = coverLocationWidth + 6;
            int LocationY = 30;
            if (AllGameInfoModel.ReleaseDate != null)//Išleidimo data
            {

                SizeF yearSize = ControlHelpers.drawString(e, "Metai:", LocationX, LocationY, null, new Font(ControlFont.FontFamily, ControlFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold));
                ControlHelpers.drawString(e, AllGameInfoModel.ReleaseDate.Value.Year.ToString(), yearSize.Width + LocationX, LocationY, null, ControlFont);

                LocationY = LocationY + (int)yearSize.Height;

                SizeF releaseDateSize = ControlHelpers.drawString(e, "Išleidimo data:", LocationX, LocationY, null, new Font(ControlFont.FontFamily, ControlFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold));
                ControlHelpers.drawString(e, AllGameInfoModel.ReleaseDate.Value.ToShortDateString(), releaseDateSize.Width + LocationX, LocationY, null, ControlFont);

                LocationY = LocationY + (int)releaseDateSize.Height;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllGameInfoModel.Genre)) //Žanras
            {
                SizeF genreSize = ControlHelpers.drawString(e, "Žanras:", LocationX, LocationY, null, new Font(ControlFont.FontFamily, ControlFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold));
                ControlHelpers.drawString(e, getGenreInLt(AllGameInfoModel.Genre), genreSize.Width + LocationX, LocationY, null, ControlFont);

                LocationY = LocationY + (int)genreSize.Height;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllGameInfoModel.DevelopersPublishers) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllGameInfoModel.Developers) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllGameInfoModel.Publishers))//Leidėjai, kūrėjai
            {
                SizeF genreSize = ControlHelpers.drawString(e, "Kūrėjai / Leidėjai:", LocationX, LocationY, null, new Font(ControlFont.FontFamily, ControlFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold));
                ControlHelpers.drawString(e, AllGameInfoModel.DevelopersPublishers, genreSize.Width + LocationX, LocationY, null, ControlFont);

                LocationY = LocationY + (int)genreSize.Height;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllGameInfoModel.Developers)) //Kūrėjai
            {
                SizeF genreSize = ControlHelpers.drawString(e, "Kūrėjai:", LocationX, LocationY, null, new Font(ControlFont.FontFamily, ControlFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold));
                ControlHelpers.drawString(e, AllGameInfoModel.Developers, genreSize.Width + LocationX, LocationY, null, ControlFont);

                LocationY = LocationY + (int)genreSize.Height;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllGameInfoModel.Publishers)) //Leidėjai
            {
                SizeF genreSize = ControlHelpers.drawString(e, "Leidėjai:", LocationX, LocationY, null, new Font(ControlFont.FontFamily, ControlFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold));
                ControlHelpers.drawString(e, AllGameInfoModel.Publishers, genreSize.Width + LocationX, LocationY, null, ControlFont);

                LocationY = LocationY + (int)genreSize.Height;
            }
            bool isPegi = false;
            if ((AllGameInfoModel.AgeQualification != null) && (AllGameInfoModel.AgeQualification != 0)) //Amžiaus cenzas
            {
                using (Bitmap picture = new Bitmap(@"Images\pegi\" + AllGameInfoModel.AgeQualification + ".gif"))
                    e.Graphics.DrawImage(picture, new Rectangle(LocationX, LocationY, pegiImageHeightWidth, pegiImageHeightWidth));//40

                using (Pen ageRectangleBrush = new Pen(Color.Black))
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(ageRectangleBrush, new Rectangle(LocationX, LocationY, pegiImageHeightWidth, pegiImageHeightWidth));

                isPegi = true;
            }

            /////Pegi Informacija//////
            int cordsX = LocationX + pegiImageHeightWidth + 5;//45
            foreach (string pegiPicture in PegiPictures)
            {
                var pegiCheck = AllGameInfoModel["Is" + pegiPicture];
                if (pegiCheck != null)
                    if (string.Equals("true", pegiCheck.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        using (Bitmap picture = new Bitmap(@"Images\Pegi\" + pegiPicture + ".gif"))
                            e.Graphics.DrawImage(picture, new Rectangle(cordsX, LocationY, pegiImageHeightWidth, pegiImageHeightWidth));

                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(componentBorderColor, new Rectangle(cordsX, LocationY, pegiImageHeightWidth, pegiImageHeightWidth));

                        cordsX = cordsX + pegiImageHeightWidth + 5;//45
                        isPegi = true;

                    }
            }
            if (isPegi)
            {
                LocationY = LocationY + pegiImageHeightWidth + 7;//47
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllGameInfoModel.Description)) //Aprašymas
            {
                descriptionFlag.Location = new Point(LocationX, LocationY + 3);
                descriptionFlag.Visible = true;

                ControlHelpers.drawString(e, "Angliškas:", LocationX + descriptionFlag.Width, LocationY + 3, null, new Font(ControlFont.FontFamily, ControlFont.Size, FontStyle.Underline | FontStyle.Bold));
                LocationY = LocationY + 20;

                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                rect.Location = new Point(LocationX, LocationY + 3);
                rect.Width = this.Width - LocationX - 1;
                if (MakeBigerControl)
                {
                    rect.Height = 300;
                }
                else
                {
                    rect.Height = 40;
                }
                //using (SolidBrush descriptionBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(Description, ControlFont, Brushes.Black, rect);


            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AllGameInfoModel.Platform)) //Platforma
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PlatformPicture))
                    using (Bitmap picture = new Bitmap(@"Images\Platforms\" + PlatformPicture + ".png"))
                        //e.Graphics.DrawImage(picture,new Rectangle(this.Width/2 + picture.Width/2, this.Height/2 - picture.Height/2,picture.Width, picture.Height)); //40
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(picture, new Rectangle(this.Width - picture.Width - 2, 27, picture.Width, picture.Height)); //40
            }
            //Draw End
        }

    }

}
```

My star control paint:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    //if (e.Graphics != null)
    //{
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        for (int i = 0; i < stars.Count; i++)
        {
            PointF[] pts = StarPoints(5, stars[i].starBounds);
            //using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black))
            e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(controlColor, pts);

            //using (SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(stars[i].backColor))
                e.Graphics.FillPolygon(stars[i].backColor, pts, FillMode.Winding); //FillMode.Winding

            SizeF textSize = ControlHelpers.MeasureString((i + 1) + "", RateFont);
            Rectangle textBounds = new Rectangle();
            textBounds.Width = stars[i].starBounds.Width;
            textBounds.Height = stars[i].starBounds.Height;
            textBounds.Location = new Point(stars[i].starBounds.X + textBounds.Width/2 - (int) textSize.Width/2,
            textBounds.Height/2 - (int) textSize.Height/2);

            //using (SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
            //using (Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 6, FontStyle.Bold))
            e.Graphics.DrawString((i + 1) + "", RateFont, Brushes.Black, textBounds);


        }

    }
```

Comment: You are passing out `e` a few times. One way to cause the error would be to mess with it in one of the called routines.. Other than that you did a good job to wrap all disposables in using clauses; that is if I didn't miss  something.. Btw: The whole drawing stuff is rather long, even borderline, imo. Maybe you could consider creating fixed Bitmaps? - The up and down in the memory consuimption is normal; the GC works as needed..

Comment: When you saying fixed bitmaps you mean to pain on bitmap? I can think about it. I dont know how to  solve that problems, becouse all resources released and what else can make crash. Maybe floatLayout panel :?

Comment: I don't see what the reason is. The usual way is to have a good look at the call stack..

Comment: mm, I get > ProgrammingTool.exe!ProgrammingTool.Controllers.RatingControl.OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e) Line 78 + 0x15 bytes C# 

  ProgrammingTool.exe!ProgrammingTool.MainWindow.MainWindowPanel.mainForm_SizeChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 63 + 0xe bytes C#
  ProgrammingTool.exe!ProgrammingTool.Program.Main() Line 16 + 0x1d bytes C#

Comment: I think sizeChanged I get after Crash becouse I resized form. Paint event 78 line mean that e.graphics null.78 line is in second example:   e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias; I dont know what we can try to solve with this messages, becouse from whem we dont get useful information :? And crash sometimes catch exception, but not all time..

Comment: As an aside, don't load any bitmaps in your paint routine. That's expensive. They need to all be loaded beforehand.